# RESTLER: use brackets to specify parameter

Tags: php, odata, restler

Similar to how OData does it, I want to use Luracast Restler with the following format to specifiy the id of an entity.

```
@url GET entity({id})
```

instead of

```
@url GET entity/{id}
```

Is there any solution for this?
If not, can this be handled by a customized router?

Thanks and regards,
Markus

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve by that!

Answer (score 1):

`CommentParser` is responsible for that, so you need to extend and tweak the comment parser